# (Android) Binding a service to an activity other than the activity that started the service

Tags: android, service

having a little trouble getting this android app to work. Basically, in the main menu I start a service that I have created, and this works fine. The problem I'm having is that I have an options activity that can be called from the main activity, and I want the options activity to be able to interact with the service that I started in the main activity.

I've read this page http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html, and I seem to have done everything right, but when I try to access some member functions of the service my program crashes. It happens specifically when I try to access a hashmap inside the service.

In my onCreate class of the options menu activity:

```
Intent passedintent = getIntent(); // gets the intent sent to the activity
        //Intent intentShim = new Intent(this, ShimmerService.class);



        // binds the shimmer service to this activity
        boolean isconnected = getApplicationContext().bindService(intent, shimmerServiceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);

     // register the shimmer receiver
        registerReceiver(shimmerReceiver, new IntentFilter("com.jpl_347E.bio_sigapp.ShimmerService"));
```

The passedintent Intent get the intent from the main activity that begins this activity. At first I tried passing this in as the 1st parameter of the

```
getApplicationContext().bindService(....)
```

function, but it didn't seem to work. So I created a new intent that mirrors the one I used to create the service in the main menu activity. I also have these functions in my options menu activity

```
 private ServiceConnection shimmerServiceConnection = new ServiceConnection() {


        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName arg0, IBinder arg1) {
            LocalShimmerBinder binder = (LocalShimmerBinder)arg1;
            serviceshim = binder.getService();
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

 };

 private BroadcastReceiver shimmerReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if (intent.getIntExtra("ShimmerState", -1) != -1)
            ;//TODO 
        }   
    };
```

It's pretty much the same code I have in my main menu activity and it is perfectly able to find the service there. I think I've traced the error to the

```
binder.getService()
```

This function is returning null, and then I try to access the hashmap in a class that my reference variable isn't pointing to (it's pointing to null).
I just can't figure out why binder.getService() would return null here and not in the main menu function. Would I perhaps need to start up the service again?
I thought that once I started the service in main, I wouldn't need to start it again in this activity.

Answer (score 1):

I realize you found a way for it to work already, but a couple of quick suggestions:

1) You don't need to call `startService` explicitly. That method is for a different use case. Binding to it will create the `Service` as necessary.

2) Don't use `getApplicationContext` from an `Activity`. The `Activity` is a `Context`, so pass `this`.

Comment: thanks for the input, what should I pass 'this' too?

Comment: Sorry, you weren't passing the application context, you were just using it. So you should just remove "getApplicationContext()." from in front of the calls to bindService.

Answer (score 0):

OOPS! It's because I was trying to use the service in my onCreate() before the ServiceConnection function could get called.